# Split yesod app source code into multiple source files

Tags: haskell, yesod

This is really a beginner question, but I cannot find anything about it on the web or on stackoverflow. Maybe I just searched wrong..

I have a yesod application where everything is in one file, and I cannot figure out how to move the functions into separate files. Here is a minimal example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Main where

import Yesod

data App = App
mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/    HomeR    GET
|]
instance Yesod App

getHomeR = defaultLayout $ toWidget [hamlet|Hello Stackoverflow|]

main = warp 8080 App
```

How do I move the `getHomeR` function into a separate file? In `getHomeR`, I need access to `App`, but `mkYesod "App"` needs access to `getHomeR`. This looks like a cyclic dependency. But somehow it must be possible to create yesod applications consisting of more than one source file.

What I *can* do is move functionality that is independent of `App` into separate files. But when `App` grows and contains more and more functionality, this becomes inconvenient, because all top level handler functions still need to be in the same file. And I don't want to use the yesod template, because I don't understand what it is doing.

---

to address a proposed solution from the comments:

> You can define the functions in your separate files, and import these in the Main. This is more or less how it is done in the yesod-mysql stack template.

error message: "No instance for (Yesod site0) arising from a use of `defaultLayout'".
And when I `import Main` in GetHomeR.hs, the error message becomes "Ambiguous type variable `site0' arising from a use of`defaultLayout'".
And when I add a `getHomeR :: Handler Html`, it compiles for a moment, but: now I have to `import GetHomeR` from Main.hs . And GHC complains with a warning about a cyclic dependency:

```
Module imports form a cycle:
         module `Main' (app\Main.hs)
        imports `GetHomeR' (app\GetHomeR.hs)
  which imports `Main' (app\Main.hs)
```

this doesn't feel right. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You can define the functions in your separate files, and import these in the `Main`. This is more or less how it is done in the `yesod-mysql` stack template. As long as `getHomeR` is in the *scope* of the `parseRoutes` you are fine, so with a simple `import` you put these in scope.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: if I do this I have an import cycle. I updated my question.

Comment: Usually in yesod the idea is that you make a `data App = App` and `instance Yesod App` in a `Foundation.hs` file, then you can import that in the `Handler.hs` file(s), and then you import these handler's in the `Main.hs` file where you thus import the `App` and the `Handler`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: hmmm, and where do I put the `mkYesod "App"` call? Actual working source code would be very appreciated :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I just looked at the templates. Actually, none of the templates use "mkYesod". They use "mkYesodData" and "mkYesodDispatch". Maybe that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out on my own.

The [mkYesodData documentation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.26/yesod-core-1.6.14/Yesod-Core-Dispatch.html#v:mkYesodData) says:

> Sometimes, you will want to declare your routes in one file and define your handlers elsewhere. For example, this is the only way to break up a monolithic file into smaller parts. Use this function, paired with mkYesodDispatch, to do just that.

You have to create a Foundation module where the `App` and the Yesod instance lives:

**Foundation.hs**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Foundation where

import Yesod

data App = App

mkYesodData "App" [parseRoutes|
/    HomeR    GET
|]

instance Yesod App
```

In your **Main.hs**, you call the routes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Main where

import Yesod
import Foundation
import GetHomeR (getHomeR)

mkYesodDispatch "App" resourcesApp

main = warp 8080 App
```

which in turn calls getHomeR from the GetHomeR module. **GetHomeR.hs**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module GetHomeR (getHomeR) where

import Yesod
import Foundation

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout $ toWidget [hamlet|Hello Stackoverflow|]
```

---

mkYesod is basically like mkYesodData + mkYesodDispatch, with the difference that mkYesodData + mkYesodDispatch cannot be in the same file because of the "stage restriction" (error message: "GHC stage restriction: `resourcesApp' is used in a top-level splice, quasi-quote, or annotation, and must be imported, not defined locally")

All the route handlers (getHomeR, ...) must be visible at the point where `mkYesodDispatch` (or `mkYesod`) is called.